# Multitouch support on KDE

Tags: kde, input

On Ubuntu there is an app called `ginn` which forces non-multitouch aware apps to support multitouch. ([source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/ginn-forcing-non-multitouch-aware-applications-to-support-multitouch-in-ubuntu/))

Is there any analogue for the KDE Desktop Environment?

Comment: I'm not sure why you couldn't just use ginn for kde apps, as well.

Comment: because Ginn is a daemon service which listens to 'gestures' from the uTouch stack, which itself is developed specifically for ubuntu. Indeed if there are ports of utouch to other platforms, the links will be greatly appreciated, as I could not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is some more information about Ginn [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/Ginn), according to the information is not dependent on utouch but a standalone daemon.

> without having to integrate uTouch-GEIS or multi-touch-enabled GTK/Qt libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It think that there's finally a neat option for those using kde based on Qt libraries, it's called Touchégg and viewing the videos on their site it really looks good.

[Touchégg site](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg)